# Is there a comprehensive list of built-in PHP functions that will throw a TypeError exception since PHP 8.0?

Tags: php, migration, php-8

I've been migrating some outdated PHP code to PHP 8.1 and noticed that since PHP 8.0 certain built-in functions will now throw a TypeError exception instead of a mere warning when the arguments passed aren't correctly typed. [See here.](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/internal-function-exceptions)

I'm quite baffled by the fact I can't seem to find a comprehensive description of this change. The code inspection tools I've ran didn't catch it either, but I can't blame them either, as this is likely a runtime issue. Some sources report all built-in functions have been promoted to throwing TypeErrors, other sources say only some functions are affected. I've already searched through the general PHP changelog for this change and was only able  to locate two affected functions, those being [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), the latter coincidentally being the one that made me aware of this issue in the codebase I'm migrating. Does this mean only these two functions are affected by the change?

If anyone is able to offer some clarity on this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I have the same question. Is it possible to keep them as a warning through some setting?

Comment: did you have really checked the "Backward Incompatible Changes" links in the PHP documentation for version migrations: https://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php

Answer (score 2):

This change was made by RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/consistent_type_errors.

All changes is here https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/3794/files

You can write a parser over PR above to get a list of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Many functions have changed from/equal 8.0 version. Mainly, from some simple functions, deleted null supporting argument. For example, in **str_replace**, **preg_replace** second argument can not be **NULL** value already. To migrate last version of PHP, you can watch consistency of PHP version, and to look from here how deprecation were.

**There are backward Incompatible Changes for PHP version 8**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php

**You can see all list new appendices**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php

Exactly, about your error (count() function) you can read from here: https://github.com/aisingapore/TagUI/issues/1137

About last version's specific PHP Type errors, you can read:
https://php.watch/versions/8.0/internal-function-exceptions

**Some migration information noted here:**

5.6 ⇾ 7.0 https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

7.3 ⇾ 7.4https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.php

7.4 ⇾ 8.0 https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.php